# When seperating function to two C files output is different

Tags: c, header-files

I have two functions one is the Algorithm and one is the main function that prints all words from a char matrix sent to the algorithm.

I get what is expected when both functions are in one C file and my char matrix is populated in the correct manner. My problem is created when I separate the main function and the algorithm to two different C files. The matrix sent to the algorithm in the other C file is filled with a lot of garbage (only around 5 lines in the matrix out of around 35 is correct and not garbage).

Why can this happen? I guess it might be how the matrix Pointer is sent.

Here is my code (disregard O(n) problems):

algorithm file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 4
#define SMALLEST_WORD 2
#define LONGEST_WORD 6
#define MAX_AMOUNT_OF_WORDS 100

int goodDirection(char* s);
void startsfrom(int i,int j);
int isWord(char* s);

int printWords(char mat[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE],
                int i,
                int j,
                int boolean[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE],
                char foundWords[MAX_AMOUNT_OF_WORDS][LONGEST_WORD],
                int currentCharIndex,
                char untilNow[LONGEST_WORD],
                int* numOfWords, 
                int usedPath[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE],
                int firstRecursive)

{
    boolean[i][j] = 1;

    char tmpUntilNow[currentCharIndex + 2];

    int i2 = 0;

    untilNow[currentCharIndex] = mat[i][j];
    untilNow[currentCharIndex + 1]= '\0';
    if(currentCharIndex > 0 ){
        if(isWord(untilNow)){

            for(i2 = 0 ;i2 < strlen(untilNow);i2++){
                foundWords[*numOfWords][i2] = untilNow[i2];
                //printf("numOfWords[i2] = %c , untilNow[i2] = %c , *numOfWords = %d ", foundWords[*numOfWords][i2] , untilNow[i2], *numOfWords);
//printf("\n");
            }
            foundWords[*numOfWords][i2] = '\0';
            *numOfWords += 1;


            foundWords[*numOfWords][0] = 'a';
            foundWords[*numOfWords][1] = 'a';
            foundWords[*numOfWords][2] = 'a';
            //foundWords[*numOfWords][0] = '\n';


            i2 =0;
        }
    }

    i2 =0;
    int j2;




    for( ; i2 < strlen(untilNow); i2++){
        tmpUntilNow[i2] = untilNow[i2];
    }
    tmpUntilNow[i2 + 1] = '\0';


    int boolean2[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

    for(i2 = 0 ; i2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;i2++){
        for(j2 = 0 ; j2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;j2++){
            boolean2[i2][j2] = boolean[i2][j2]; 
        }
    }


    if(currentCharIndex < LONGEST_WORD){
        if( i-1 >= 0){
            if(!(boolean2[i-1][j])){
                //currentCharIndex + 1 is same as i2. I thought that this is more logical to write for coherency.
                tmpUntilNow[currentCharIndex + 1] = mat[i-1][j];

                if(goodDirection(tmpUntilNow) ){
                        printWords(mat,i-1,j,boolean2,foundWords,currentCharIndex + 1,tmpUntilNow, numOfWords, usedPath, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        for(i2 = 0 ; i2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;i2++){
            for(j2 = 0 ; j2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;j2++){
                boolean2[i2][j2] = boolean[i2][j2]; 
            }
        }


        if( j-1 >= 0){
            if(!(boolean2[i][j-1])){
                tmpUntilNow[currentCharIndex + 1] = mat[i][j-1];
                if(goodDirection(tmpUntilNow)){
                        printWords(mat,i,j-1,boolean2,foundWords,currentCharIndex + 1,tmpUntilNow, numOfWords, usedPath, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        for(i2 = 0 ; i2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;i2++){
            for(j2 = 0 ; j2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;j2++){
                boolean2[i2][j2] = boolean[i2][j2]; 
            }
        }

        if(i+1 <= MATRIX_SIZE){
            if(!(boolean2[i+1][j])){
                tmpUntilNow[currentCharIndex + 1] = mat[i+1][j];
                if(goodDirection(tmpUntilNow) ){
                        printWords(mat,i+1,j,boolean2,foundWords,currentCharIndex + 1,tmpUntilNow, numOfWords, usedPath, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        for(i2 = 0 ; i2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;i2++){
            for(j2 = 0 ; j2 < MATRIX_SIZE ;j2++){
                boolean2[i2][j2] = boolean[i2][j2]; 
            }
        }

        if(j+1 <= MATRIX_SIZE){
            //printf(" i is : %d , and j is %d and boolen is: %d\n",i, j+1,(boolean[i][j+1]));
            if(!(boolean2[i][j+1])){
                tmpUntilNow[currentCharIndex + 1] = mat[i][j+1];
                if(goodDirection(tmpUntilNow) ){
                        printWords(mat,i,j+1,boolean2,foundWords,currentCharIndex + 1,tmpUntilNow, numOfWords, usedPath, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

main file:

```
      #include <stdio.h>
        #include "matrixWords.h"
        #include <string.h>

    //#include <string.h>

    #define MATRIX_SIZE 4
    #define SMALLEST_WORD 3
    #define LONGEST_WORD 5
    #define MAX_AMOUNT_OF_WORDS 100





#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrixWords.h"
#include <string.h>

//#include <string.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 4
#define SMALLEST_WORD 3
#define LONGEST_WORD 5
#define MAX_AMOUNT_OF_WORDS 100





    int main() {
        char matrix [4] [4] = {{'C','A','R','T'},{'E','T','A','K'},{'E','S','M','E'},{'L','L','P','N'}};
        //char test [1][1];
        char foundWords[MAX_AMOUNT_OF_WORDS][LONGEST_WORD];
        char untilNow[LONGEST_WORD + 1];
        untilNow[0] = matrix[0][0];
        int usedPath[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE] = {{0}};
        int numOfWords = 0;

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for(; i < MATRIX_SIZE ; i++){
            for(; j< MATRIX_SIZE ;j++){
                int boolean[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE] = {{0}};
                printWords(matrix,i,j,boolean,foundWords,0,untilNow,&numOfWords,usedPath,1);
            }
            j= 0;
        }

        int flag = 1;
        int a = 0;
        for(; a < MAX_AMOUNT_OF_WORDS && flag; a++){
            if(foundWords[a][1] == 'a'){
                flag = 0;
            }
            int b = 0;
            char word[LONGEST_WORD];
            //printf("\n \n");
            for(;b<LONGEST_WORD - 1;b++){
                word[b] = foundWords[a][b];
                //printf("foundWords[a][b] is %c   \n",foundWords[a][b] );
            }
            word[b] = '\0';

            int j = 0, flag2 = 1;
            for(; j < b && flag2 ; j++){
                if(isWord(word)){
                    flag2 = 0;
                    b = 0;
                    for(;b < strlen(word); b++){
                        //Tomer chack
                        printf("%c",word[b]);
                    }
                    printf(",\n");

                }
                else{
                    //printf("%c and a is %d \n",foundWords[a][0], a);
                    --b;
                    word[b] = '\0';
                }

            }

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

By the way, this is my first course working with C, therefore, I am a newbie on this subject.

Output:

Good output:

> CAT, CATS, CAR, CART, ATE, ART, RAT, RATS, RAT, RATS, RAMP, RAKE,
>   RAKE, TRAM, TRAMS, TAME, TAKE, TAKEN, TAKE, ART, ATE, STEEL, STAMP,
>   SELL, SELL, MAKE, MAKE, ME, MEN,

Bad output:

> CAT, ART, RAMP, TAME, ATE, MAKE,

Comment: You should put your `#defines` in a header file, and include that header file in both of your `.c` files.  For example, `LONGEST_WORD` is defined differently in the two files, and that is definitely part of the problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I now tried this but I got the following error:

error: ‘MATRIX_SIZE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 int printWords(char mat[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE],

Comment: Create a header file with your shared terms and put it in BOTH C files.

Comment: And why do you `#define` the same stuff twice in the same C file??

Comment: Hi,
Well you were right I really didnt include the header file in both of the files

Comment: @user3386109 You were also right this did the trick! Why did this matter? I mean from my understanding putting the define in the header file and not in the c file was only better practice, but not functionally different. Also, do you want to copy that as an answer so I can close the question as answered?

Comment: if you have the same value defined differently in different c files, it will most certainly affect the functionality of the code